# Do OpenMP and OpenCL use primitives like POSIX threads and POSIX mutex on their implementation on UNIX systems?

Tags: opencl, openmp

Do OpenMP and OpenCL use primitives like POSIX threads and POSIX mutex on their implementation on UNIX systems or do they use their own implementation ?

Comment: OpenMP always sits on top of Pthreads on Linux. Not required but that's how everyone does it.

Comment: The concept of threads might be given for mainly CPU-based library implementations like OpenMP. I don't think, you can talk about threads in devices like GPUs, FPGAs, DSPs etc with OpenCL running on.